# How is computed the train data set score and why?

Tags: machine-learning, metric

In a lot of machine learning blogs or review, the training dataset accuracy (or other metric) is given alongside the test dataset score. Is this score calculated through the training, or is the training data given at the final model to see if it gives a good score ?

Moreover, what is the point of computing such a score, as the model has been trained with this data ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Overfitting

Computing the training score and the test score is usefull to detect overfitting

for exemple here we can see that the training score (in blue) keep improving but at some point the test score (in red) stop improving, that's the sign of overfitting.

[image: from wikipedia]

But for a final model the training score is not usefull and only the test score should be used.

Comment: Thanks, but is the training score computed alongside the training or is it computed at each epoch i.e. all the training set is ut through the current model at time t ?

Comment: for each epoch I compute the total loss of the epoch on the training set and the loss on the test set